# How to change widget background color without losing it's layout corners?

Tags: android, colors, background, widget

I am trying to change widget background color dynamically, but I lose the corners of my background layout (which uses colorless shape as a background), when I set background color.

In other words when I choose custom color for background and I apply it to the background it acts as I have applied a whole background drawable.

So how can this be done in other way, in order not to lose the layout corners, because without corners the widget looks bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add ImageView as a background, to your primary layout (fill_parent), and set its background to  @drawable/background_with_corners which has the following code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

And then from your code call`remoteViews.setInt(R.id.backgroundimage, "setColorFilter", color);` to apply the selected color to the image retaining the shape.

And if your color has transparency call `remoteViews.setInt(R.id.backgroundimage, "setImageAlpha", Color.alpha(color);` if SDK>=16; else `remoteViews.setInt(R.id.backgroundimage, "setAlpha", Color.alpha(color);`

I hope this helps.